# R Markdown script and R

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am calling one R Markdown script from another R script.Below you can see command

```
rmarkdown::render((file=paste(path1,"/Dashboard.Rmd",sep="")),params=list(args = myarg))
```

The script is executed without any problem but is not open automatically.

So can anybody help me how to solve this problem and open this script automatically after running of this command ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your syntax probably isn't doing what you intended.  Writing

```
rmarkdown::render((file=paste(path1,"/Dashboard.Rmd",sep="")),params=list(args = myarg))
```

will create a new variable named `file` and use it as the first parameter to `rmarkdown::render`.  A more likely way to get what you want is to write it as

```
outfile <- rmarkdown::render(paste(path1,"/Dashboard.Rmd",sep=""),
                             params=list(args = myarg))
```

This removes the assignment from the first argument, and saves the
result (which is the name of the file that was produced).

Now, on to your question:  You need to follow that line with

```
rstudioapi::viewer(outfile)
```

to view it in RStudio, or

```
browseURL(outfile)
```

elsewhere, because `rmarkdown::render` doesn't automatically call a previewer.